# How do I control breathing during hanging leg raises?

Tags: abdominals, breathing, calisthenics

I usually don't have any serious issues with controlling my breath during exercising, but with hanging leg raises it's just something else. I'm literally unable to exhale while raising my legs and inhale while lowering them. I always end up having to take a short break after each rep just to get my breath back. How do I improve my breathing here?

Comment: Focus on contracting your abdominals during the upwards movement. Hold you breath for the entire movement and breathe out once you have retuned to starting position. That way you will be working your abs the whole time.

Comment: So, basically, what the other answer says, right? I don't breathe during the repetition, but I both exhale and then inhale once I'm in the starting position again. Right?

Comment: Correct, I only commented because this is primarily opinion based.

Comment: No problem, the breathing method can be transferred into nearly every other lift because it helps your maintain tightness in your core to provide stabilization, especially at heavier weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach -- breathing between repetitions of hanging leg-raises -- is acceptable.  Breathing during the repetition is unnecessary.